# ActiveMQ NIO configuration

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, nio

I am exploring the option of switching from **tcp** to **nio** in *ActiveMQ*.
The [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html) gives an example of this, in which only the scheme of the URI is changed in the broker's xml configuration:

```
<broker>
  ...
  <transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="nio" uri="nio://0.0.0.0:61616"/>  
  </<transportConnectors>
  ...
</broker>
```

**Question:** Then, do I also have to change the scheme of the client configuration to match? For example,

```
<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsConnectionFactory" brokerURL="nio://localhost:61616?"/>
```

This seems to be a source of confusion for others as well:

- http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-NIO-protocol-td3540710.html.
- http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/NIO-freezes-client-td2361338.html.

These threads claim that NIO only needs to be configured for the broker, but is there any **official documentation** to support this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to change the client from tcp or whatever to NIO, the broker is the only side that would use or have any benefit of NIO as the client maintains a single open connection.  Even if you do change to NIO the code is smart enough underneath to know that the client is requesting NIO and swaps in a TCP factory so you still end up with the same thing in the end.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I expect, but is this documented anywhere?

Comment: See the transport descriptions on this page: http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html